# Mongo Query by Partial document?

Tags: mongodb

Essentially, I want to query mongo return documents that contain matching keys from a partially defined json object.

**Example document:**

```
{ 
    "description" : { 
        "body" : { 
            "type" : "Ectomorph", 
            "shape" : "Spoon", 
            "muscle tone" : "Moderately Tone" 
        } 
    }
}
```

**How I'm attempting to query**

```
db.taxonomy.find({ description: { $elemMatch: { body: { type: "Ectomorph" } } } })
```

Although, according to the mongo documentation `$elemMatch` appears to be the operator i want to use, it doesn't appear to be working this way.

**Note**

I'm aware that the query would work if it was writting as `{ "decription.body.type": "Ectomorph" }`

But the key values I'm searching by are coming from a request and i'd rather not waste processing power parsing the JSON into a query like this if i don't have to.

Comment: `$elemMatch` operator works on arrays, not ordinary objects. see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: $elemMatch is actually for arrays.
I also didn't really understand how making a query like: { description: { $elemMatch: { body: { type: "Ectomorph" } } } } differs from { "decription.body.type": "Ectomorph" } in terms of processing power. Could you provide an example of how the request looks like?

Comment: processing power in that i would have to manually rewrite the object.

anyway the request looks the same as the example:

    { 
        body: { 
            type: "Ectomorph" 
        } 
    }